# Can't test post request in postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, controller, postman

[image: I have been gettting this error (displayed in the picture) while trying to post requesnt in postman. I am trying to post and update restaurant item but haven't been able to update it without manually doing so in the seed.rb file in rails. I have index function for get, create function for post and update function for put/update.]

I have been gettting this error (displayed in the picture) while trying to post requesnt in postman. I am trying to post and update restaurant item but haven't been able to update it without manually doing so in the seed.rb file in rails. I have index function for get, create function for post and update function for put/update. I am expecting to update post and delete the list of restaurants through postman.

Comment: What are you using for your token?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line in API Controller:**

```
class PostsController < ApiController
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).